# Split name list by gender

Tags: python, sorting, split, tuples

I have a problem with my code. I must create a function that given a list of names (male and female) creates two new lists.

One with the male and the other with the female names. The problem is that these are Polish names, so female names end with `a`.

This is what I have so far:

```
names = ["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"]
names.sort()

print(names)

def name_sorter(names):
    male =sorted(key=lambda x:x.split[-1])

print(name_sorter(names))
```

Comment: what you describe as *problem* is actually *really good news*; it makes the splitting from nightmarish to piece of cake.

Comment: But note that saying *female names end with "a"* is not the same as saying *all names that end with "a" are female names*.

Answer (score 2):

```
females = []
males = []
for name in names:
    if name.endswith("a"):
        females.append(name)
    else:
        males.append(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a single statement in a loop with:

```
names = sorted(["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"])

females, males = [], []
for name in names:
    (females if name[-1] == "a" else males).append(name)

print(females)  # -> ['Alicja', 'Barbara']
print(males)    # -> ['Andrzej', 'Cezary', 'Henryk']
```

Here's another possibility that still very readable (if you understand Python):

```
males = []
females = [name for name in names if name[-1] == "a" or males.append(name)]
```

Just thought of another variation which (very appropriately) uses `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

names = sorted(["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"])

males, females = [], []
for sex, firstnames in groupby(names, lambda name: name[-1] == "a"):
    [males, females][sex].extend(firstnames)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
female_names = [i for i in names if i.endswith('a')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your list `names`, then you can simply iterate through it and add males to one list and females to another:

```
names = ["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"]
males = []
females = []
for name in names:
    if name[-1] == 'a':
        females.append(name)
    else:
        males.append(name)
```

And then you can sort them if you wish like normal:

```
females.sort()
males.sort()
```

Comment: Why do two sorts at the end when you could do one at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"]

females = [name for name in names if name[-1] == 'a']
males = [name for name in names if name not in females]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.endswith()`:

```
names = ["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"]

males = []
females = []

for name in names:
    if name.endswith("a"):
        females.append(name)
    else:
        males.append(name)

print(males, females)
```

Output:

```
['Andrzej', 'Henryk', 'Cezary'] ['Alicja', 'Barbara']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.endswith()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm):

```
names = ["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"]

males = [m for m in names if not m.endswith('a')]  # ['Andrzej', 'Henryk', 'Cezary']
females = [f for f in names if f not in males]      # ['Alicja', 'Barbara']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ["Andrzej", "Henryk", "Alicja", "Cezary", "Barbara"]
for name in names:
    if name.endswith("a") == True:
        print("F")
    else:
        print("M")
```

Comment: This does not "split" the list.

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why,  to help others identify the problem and understand this answer